# Where does Apple Configurator store ipsw downloads?

Tags: macos, ios, mobile-device-management, apple-configurator

Every time Apple releases new iOS software, it's a bit of a rush to get things downloaded and the servers can be slow in delivering the bits.

I would like to know where the Apple Configurator Version 1.2.1 (169) stores downloaded iOS software so I could transfer the files from iTunes or another computer so I can have several machines grab one each of the builds and then distribute them to avoid having each machine have to re-download all images each time.

Can I move IPSW in to or out of Apple Configurator rather than having it control the downloads from Apple for iOS software?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since Apple Configurator 2.0 they are downloaded in:

```
~/Library/Group Containers/K36BKF7T3D.group.com.apple.configurator/Library/Caches/Downloads/ACUDownloadFileOperation/
```

and stored in:

```
~/Library/Group Containers/K36BKF7T3D.group.com.apple.configurator/Library/Caches/Firmware
```

Answer (score 4):

I've figured out how to point Apple Configurator at the IPSW that iTunes has downloaded as follows:

[image: Do not use Latest for iOS]

Then use the dialog with Other... to add each and every IPSW that you've already downloaded. Since ~Library is normally hidden, you may need the go to shortcut to type command-shift-G and then `~/Library/iTunes` to get to the filesystem location where iTunes has downloaded current IPSW files.

[image: Apple Configurator]

By adding multiple iOS versions, you can point the configurator at already downloaded IPSW and avoid the wait / duplication of Configurator re-downloading the same file and storing it away in some obfuscated database file at `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.configurator/Data/Library/Application Support/com.apple.configurator/Resources`

I haven't found a way to remove IPSW from Apple Configurator, but knowing I can keep them where iTunes prefers is workable for my case when I'd rather not wait for a long download and/or a duplicate set of IPSW on a particular Mac.

Answer (score 3):

I am using version 1.3.1 (274) of Apple configurator, the following worked for me:

[Apple Configurator: Managing iOS device software](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5782) had the correct location for the IPSW files in my situation.

```
~/Library/Containers/com.apple.configurator/Data/Library/Caches/com.apple.configurator/Firmware/
```

I had to create the Firmware folder as it didn't exist yet but it I was able to successfully copy the required IPSW file to this location and deploy it to an iPhone without AC going to the internet to download it again.

Comment: I was so happy when Apple revamped the storage of IPSW when it released v 1.3 of the configurator.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the *IPSWs* are stored under `~/Library/Application Support/com.apple.configurator/IPSWs` .

The *IPSWs*, stored per device's model and iOS version, are automatically downloaded here when you perform a restore using the **Apple Configurator**.

So, copying, the newest *IPSW* into this directory should do the trick.

Comment: Hmm - I have no such folder on either of my Mac that are running Version 1.2.1 (169) of Apple Configurator. When I run `mdfind ipsw` only the hits from ~/Library/iTunes/ are returned, so I presume this version of the configurator has squirreled the updates away in a database rather than parking them in the filesystem. :(

Comment: +1 since your answer got me to the answer I needed. Looking over my Time Machine backups, that folder indeed did used to exist - but the database for Apple Configurator is now at ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.configurator and the IPSW are not stored on the filesystem so I need to use the tool to point at the IPSW iTunes has downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

Apple Configurator Version 1.5 (424):

```
~/Library/Containers/com.apple.configurator/Data/Library/Caches/com.apple.configurator/Firmware
```

I copied the manually downloaded files to the location above. Apple Configurator used those files to update my devices. You may want to note, Configurator still requires an internet connection to run. I suggest submitting a feature request to support updating devices while offline.

Answer (score 0):

Apple Configurator Version 1.7.1 (550) checks `~/Library/iTunes/iPad Software Updates` for `iPad _Restore.ipsw` files.

Placing files in the appropriate directory

```
~/Library/iTunes/<some iOS device>
```

It is easy to remember and it makes sense for Configurator to be looking here in case an iOS device has been restored or updated using iTunes.